# Release code to production best practices

Tags: tfs

in my current job we have a very complicated process to pass stuff to production to production (we use TFS, and a lot of tiny apps to generate labels, store the store procedures code, etc)  but it's necesary have some controls because we be ruled by SOX, so, what could be a good aproach to have a simple and clean source control (and a very fast pass to production)
Here's the process

1.- Do the check in

2.- Create a label with a external tool (with the changeset)

3.- Store the sp's with another external tool

4.- integrate all the changes made by the different teams

5.- put all together in production if we are lucky enough to no have conflicts

there's no way to simplify this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the app you are deploying? What does your deployment process look like today?

Answer (score 0):

maybe a combination of Hudson, ANT scripts, and SVN.